# The identifier that starts with 'xxxxxx........' is too long. Maximum length is 128

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sql-server-2012

there are many space in sql query (column name) that entity framework 6 are generated!
below is a sample code that called

"factors" table have a "BaseDiscountPrice" column name
and entities is ObjectSet< Factor >

```
 public List<Factor> GetTodayFactors()
        {
            try
            {
       
                return entities.AsNoTracking().Where(f =>  f.OwnerRef == Access.Login.CurrentUser.ID).OrderByDescending(p => p.ID).Take(40).Include(p => p.Customer).ToList();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log
                return null;
            }
        }
```

causes error:
this is error stack

```
Exception classes:   
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException
   System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException

Exception messages: 
   The identifier that starts with 'BaseDiscountP...................................................................................................................' is too long. Maximum length is 128.
   An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Stack Traces:
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
--- Next Call Stack:
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetResults>b__5()
   at System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.DefaultSqlExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at BuySell.BusinessLayer.BLFactor.GetTodayFactors()
```

we have sql server profiler side:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (40) 
    [Project1].[ID] AS [ID], 
    [Project1].[Date] AS [Date], 
    [Project1].[CustomerRef] AS [CustomerRef], 
    [Project1].[TypeRef] AS [TypeRef], 
    [Project1].[ProductSumPrice] AS [ProductSumPrice], 
    [Project1].[DiscountPercent] AS [DiscountPercent], 
    [Project1].[DiscountPrice] AS [DiscountPrice], 
    [Project1].[RealSum] AS [RealSum], 
    [Project1].[Profit] AS [Profit], 
    [Project1].[Description] AS [Description], 
    [Project1].[DeductionsSum] AS [DeductionsSum], 
    [Project1].[IsTemp] AS [IsTemp], 
    [Project1].[DefrayDate] AS [DefrayDate], 
    [Project1].[AdditionsSum] AS [AdditionsSum], 
    [Project1].[OrginalFactorID] AS [OrginalFactorID], 
    [Project1].[RecPayAmount] AS [RecPayAmount], 
    [Project1].[Tax] AS [Tax], 
    [Project1].[RemainAmount] AS [RemainAmount], 
    [Project1].[Serial] AS [Serial], 
    [Project1].[Settlement] AS [Settlement], 
    [Project1].[VisitorRef] AS [VisitorRef], 
    [Project1].[VisitorAmount] AS [VisitorAmount], 
    [Project1].[Attachment] AS [Attachment], 
    [Project1].[ItemGroupRef] AS [ItemGroupRef], 
    [Project1].[OwnerRef] AS [OwnerRef], 
    [Project1].[Flag] AS [Flag], 
    [Project1].[VisitorPercent] AS [VisitorPercent], 
    [Project1].[Currency] AS [Currency], 
    [Project1].[CurrencyValue] AS [CurrencyValue], 
    [Project1].[TaxPercent] AS [TaxPercent], 
    [Project1].[DocID] AS [DocID], 
    [Project1].[CurrencyRef] AS [CurrencyRef], 
    [Project1].[CurrencyRatio] AS [CurrencyRatio], 
    [Project1].[BaseProductSumPrice] AS [BaseProductSumPrice], 
    [Project1].[BaseDiscountPrice] AS [BaseDiscountPrice], 
    [Project1].[BaseRealSum] AS [BaseRealSum], 
    [Project1].[BaseProfit] AS [BaseProfit], 
    [Project1].[BaseDeductionsSum] AS [BaseDeductionsSum], 
    [Project1].[BaseAdditionsSum] AS [BaseAdditionsSum], 
    [Project1].[BaseRecPayAmount] AS [BaseRecPayAmount], 
    [Project1].[BaseTax] AS [BaseTax], 
    [Project1].[BaseRemainAmount] AS [BaseRemainAmount], 
    [Project1].[BaseVisitorAmount] AS [BaseVisitorAmount], 
    [Project1].[ID1] AS [ID1], 
    [Project1].[Code] AS [Code], 
    [Project1].[Name] AS [Name], 
    [Project1].[Description1] AS [Description1], 
    [Project1].[Tel] AS [Tel], 
    [Project1].[Mobile] AS [Mobile], 
    [Project1].[Fax] AS [Fax], 
    [Project1].[Address] AS [Address], 
    [Project1].[SumPrice] AS [SumPrice], 
    [Project1].[FirstPrice] AS [FirstPrice], 
    [Project1].[Pic] AS [Pic], 
    [Project1].[UntoldLastDate] AS [UntoldLastDate], 
    [Project1].[Email] AS [Email], 
    [Project1].[DateCreate] AS [DateCreate], 
    [Project1].[Active] AS [Active], 
    [Project1].[NationalCode] AS [NationalCode], 
    [Project1].[PostCode] AS [PostCode], 
    [Project1].[EconomicCode] AS [EconomicCode], 
    [Project1].[Province] AS [Province], 
    [Project1].[TownShip] AS [TownShip], 
    [Project1].[Town] AS [Town], 
    [Project1].[ItemGroupRef1] AS [ItemGroupRef1], 
    [Project1].[Type] AS [Type], 
    [Project1].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
    [Project1].[PerDayFactor] AS [PerDayFactor], 
    [Project1].[SumBuy] AS [SumBuy], 
    [Project1].[Rank] AS [Rank], 
    [Project1].[Credit] AS [Credit], 
    [Project1].[DocID1] AS [DocID1], 
    [Project1].[Date1] AS [Date1], 
    [Project1].[TypeRef1] AS [TypeRef1], 
    [Project1].[VisitorRef1] AS [VisitorRef1]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Extent1].[ID] AS [ID], 
        [Extent1].[Date] AS [Date], 
        [Extent1].[CustomerRef] AS [CustomerRef], 
        [Extent1].[TypeRef] AS [TypeRef], 
        [Extent1].[ProductSumPrice] AS [ProductSumPrice], 
        [Extent1].[DiscountPercent] AS [DiscountPercent], 
        [Extent1].[DiscountPrice] AS [DiscountPrice], 
        [Extent1].[RealSum] AS [RealSum], 
        [Extent1].[Profit] AS [Profit], 
        [Extent1].[Description] AS [Description], 
        [Extent1].[DeductionsSum] AS [DeductionsSum], 
        [Extent1].[IsTemp] AS [IsTemp], 
        [Extent1].[DefrayDate] AS [DefrayDate], 
        [Extent1].[AdditionsSum] AS [AdditionsSum], 
        [Extent1].[OrginalFactorID] AS [OrginalFactorID], 
        [Extent1].[RecPayAmount] AS [RecPayAmount], 
        [Extent1].[Tax] AS [Tax], 
        [Extent1].[RemainAmount] AS [RemainAmount], 
        [Extent1].[Serial] AS [Serial], 
        [Extent1].[Settlement] AS [Settlement], 
        [Extent1].[VisitorRef] AS [VisitorRef], 
        [Extent1].[VisitorAmount] AS [VisitorAmount], 
        [Extent1].[Attachment] AS [Attachment], 
        [Extent1].[ItemGroupRef] AS [ItemGroupRef], 
        [Extent1].[OwnerRef] AS [OwnerRef], 
        [Extent1].[Flag] AS [Flag], 
        [Extent1].[VisitorPercent] AS [VisitorPercent], 
        [Extent1].[Currency] AS [Currency], 
        [Extent1].[CurrencyValue] AS [CurrencyValue], 
        [Extent1].[TaxPercent] AS [TaxPercent], 
        [Extent1].[DocID] AS [DocID], 
        [Extent1].[CurrencyRef] AS [CurrencyRef], 
        [Extent1].[CurrencyRatio] AS [CurrencyRatio], 
        [Extent1].[BaseProductSumPrice] AS [BaseProductSumPrice], 
        [Extent1].[BaseDiscountP                                                                                                                                                                                                                     1].[BaseAdditionsSum] AS [BaseAdditionsSum], 
        [Extent1].[BaseRecPayAmount] AS [BaseRecPayAmount], 
        [Extent1].[BaseTax] AS [BaseTax], 
        [Extent1].[BaseRemainAmount] AS [BaseRemainAmount], 
        [Extent1].[BaseVisitorAmount] AS [BaseVisitorAmount], 
        [Extent2].[ID] AS [ID1], 
        [Extent2].[Code] AS [Code], 
        [Extent2].[Name] AS [Name], 
        [Extent2].[Description] AS [Description1], 
        [Extent2].[Tel] AS [Tel], 
        [Extent2].[Mobile] AS [Mobile], 
        [Extent2].[Fax] AS [Fax], 
        [Extent2].[Address] AS [Address], 
        [Extent2].[SumPrice] AS [SumPrice], 
        [Extent2].[FirstPrice] AS [FirstPrice], 
        [Extent2].[Pic] AS [Pic], 
        [Extent2].[UntoldLastDate] AS [UntoldLastDate], 
        [Extent2].[Email] AS [Email], 
        [Extent2].[DateCreate] AS [DateCreate], 
        [Extent2].[Active] AS [Active], 
        [Extent2].[NationalCode] AS [NationalCode], 
        [Extent2].[PostCode] AS [PostCode], 
        [Extent2].[EconomicCode] AS [EconomicCode], 
        [Extent2].[Province] AS [Province], 
        [Extent2].[TownShip] AS [TownShip], 
        [Extent2].[Town] AS [Town], 
        [Extent2].[ItemGroupRef] AS [ItemGroupRef1], 
        [Extent2].[Type] AS [Type], 
        [Extent2].[RowVersion] AS [RowVersion], 
        [Extent2].[PerDayFactor] AS [PerDayFactor], 
        [Extent2].[SumBuy] AS [SumBuy], 
        [Extent2].[Rank] AS [Rank], 
        [Extent2].[Credit] AS [Credit], 
        [Extent2].[DocID] AS [DocID1], 
        [Extent2].[Date] AS [Date1], 
        [Extent2].[TypeRef] AS [TypeRef1], 
        [Extent2].[VisitorRef] AS [VisitorRef1]
        FROM  [dbo].[Factors] AS [Extent1]
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Customers] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CustomerRef] = [Extent2].[ID]
        WHERE ((DATEDIFF (day, SysDateTime(), [Extent1].[Date])) < 1) AND ([Extent1].[OwnerRef] = @p__linq__0)
    )  AS [Project1]
    ORDER BY [Project1].[ID] DESC',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=1
```

"[Extent1].[BaseDiscountP......."(213 spaces) must be "BaseDiscountPrice" actually

why EF6 not generate sql command Properly ? thank you
[image]

Comment: Format your code so people can read it. Putting everything into one long line offers no benefits

Comment: In any case it's impossible to say what's going on without the actual entities. What properties are there, how are they defined? Do they have any attributes that change their name? What is the DbContext's configuration, at least for those properties?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It's hard to spot, but I think the horizontal scrolling at least is to try and demonstrate that the line `[Extent1].[BaseDiscountP` has unexplained spaces in the name (scroll all the way right when that line is in view). I would say either stop using an ORM to write your SQL because they are generally not great at that, but also try removing and re-adding that column. The spaces came from somewhere, it isn't gremlins.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I was talking about the LINQ query. It's hard to tell what's wrong with a property that doesn't even appear in the query

Comment: i have only one line of code and the next is trace stack and next is sql server profiler

Comment: @ShahirSoft exactly. One long line of code that doesn't even fit on the screen. Split it so people can read it. And post the entities and the dbcontext configuration. There's no `BaseDiscount` property in your LINQ query. Where did it come from? How was it configured? That's where the problem is

Comment: Can you check/add the class definition for Factor and Customer, or entity type configuration? If I had to guess I suspect you might have something like a `[Column()]` attribute that you've accidentally added a carriage return into the middle of the name and it's thinking the column name now has a slew of spaces in it..

Comment: "factors" table have a "BaseDiscountPrice" column name and entities is ObjectSet< Factor >

Comment: in sql side instade of "BaseDiscountPrice" i have "[BaseDiscountP...(213 spaces)" query genrated by entity framework automatically

Comment: project is model first and models are crated by visual studio auto not manually (file .edmx ,

Comment: Fix it in the model, @steve-py is correct, this is usually the result of a carriage return. Show us the model config for that column, you can also edit the edmx file direct if it is too hard to spot in the designer

Comment: .edmx file
         <EntitySetMapping Name="Factors">
            <EntityTypeMapping TypeName="RoboAccDBModel.Factor">
              <MappingFragment StoreEntitySet="Factors">
                <ScalarProperty Name="BaseDiscountPrice" ColumnName="BaseDiscountPrice" />

Comment: Hmm, I'm not that familiar with using edmx for config. Try opening that file in Notepad and find that BaseDiscountPrice field to double-check there isn't something weird in the file that the designer/code window might be hiding.  Definitely a very weird error to encounter but there must be something in there. Also check that RoboAccDbModel.Factor class for any attributes, as well as the DbContext `OnModelCreating` method in case someone added any manual configuration.

Comment: What does `SELECT name, LEN(name), ASCII(RIGHT(name,1)) FROM sys.columns WHERE name LIKE N'BaseDiscountP%' AND [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Factors');` yield? What happens if you right-click the column in Object Explorer, choose Rename, and then type in that space `BaseDiscountPrice` and hit enter? Does the problem disappear? It sounds like the column name has been saved with a bunch of junk in it that Object Explorer doesn't display.

Comment: select resualt: BaseDiscountPrice 17 101